# Failed to return the unique result

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In my user table, it contains users that consist of three roles which is admin, lecturer, student. I want to retrieve only the student user details from the user table.

But it show this exception `org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException` when I run the program to get the data from **user** table

**Exception display in the console**

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_3_, user0_.edu_inst as edu_inst2_3_, user0_.email as email3_3_, user0_.gender as gender4_3_, user0_.password as password5_3_, user0_.user_role as user_rol6_3_, user0_.username as username7_3_ from user user0_ where user0_.user_role='Student'
Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_4_0_, roles0_.role_id as role_id2_4_0_, role1_.id as id1_1_1_, role1_.name as name2_1_1_ from users_roles roles0_ inner join roles role1_ on roles0_.role_id=role1_.id where roles0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_4_0_, roles0_.role_id as role_id2_4_0_, role1_.id as id1_1_1_, role1_.name as name2_1_1_ from users_roles roles0_ inner join roles role1_ on roles0_.role_id=role1_.id where roles0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_4_0_, roles0_.role_id as role_id2_4_0_, role1_.id as id1_1_1_, role1_.name as name2_1_1_ from users_roles roles0_ inner join roles role1_ on roles0_.role_id=role1_.id where roles0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_4_0_, roles0_.role_id as role_id2_4_0_, role1_.id as id1_1_1_, role1_.name as name2_1_1_ from users_roles roles0_ inner join roles role1_ on roles0_.role_id=role1_.id where roles0_.user_id=?
2022-02-16 15:20:07.678  INFO 1812 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Committed transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@6986bbaf testClass = UserRepositoryTest, testInstance = com.fyp.webapp.UserRepositoryTest@5cde6747, testMethod = testFindStudentUserByRole@UserRepositoryTest, testException = org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: query did not return a unique result: 4; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 4, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@4879dfad testClass = UserRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.fyp.webapp.FypWebAppApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}'
```

**My user bean class**

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 100)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 85)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "gender", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String gender;

    @Column(name = "userRole", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String role;

    @Column(name = "edu_inst", nullable = false, length = 65)
    private String eduInst;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

**My user repository code**

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.role = 'Student' ")
    User findStudentUserByRole();
```

**user table**

> [image]

**user_roles table**

> [image]

**role table**

> [image]

Comment: You have more than one user fulfilling the WHERE selection. Thus you cannot return a single user in your repository method.

Comment: I want to display the records of the student user, not only single user record

Answer (score 2):

Change signature `User findStudentUserByRole()` to `List<User> findStudentUserByRole()`